# Fast Way To Check Many Bluetooth Devices by MAC Address

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm creating a tool that checks for the presence of many (~100) bluetooth devices.  I'll have their MAC addresses already.  I just want to know if they're in range, even if **not** set to discoverable.

Using `hcitool name <bt_addr>` does this.  But it's not very fast; it takes up to 5 seconds to check each address, especially if the device is not in range.  If I fork parallel subprocesses, it still takes up to 5 seconds each, as if bluez or something in the stack is serializing the requests.

Is there a faster way to check for the presence of BT devices by MAC address?  I don't need to know the names of them, just if they're around (whether set discoverable or not).  Ideally I'd like to check all ~100 in half a minute or less.

Bonus points if the solution doesn't require sudo (like l2ping), but OK if that's the only way.  Platform is Ubuntu Linux, using a Cambridge Silicon BT dongle if it matters...

Thanx,

-- Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No 
If the device is not discoverable then there is no fast and effecting way.
Any other scheme (including requesting the name) requires establishing a connection - which will take few seconds each, there is no way the connection process can be done in parallel at the radio - it is one at a time.

Comment: Thanx.  Hmmm... I could add more radios; a BT dongle is cheap.  Does the bluez stack support multiple radios? if I use 8 radios that would get it around a minute to check a hundred addresses.  -- Steve

Comment: Please do accept & vote up the answer if it was useful. You can use multiple radios and run an instance of Bluez on each and this can implement some parallelism.

Comment: Update:  I tested with four bluetooth dongles, and was able to do four requests at a time, in five seconds or less.  So the solution is simply to add more radios.  At a buck each, it's the easy solution!